# Error 1004 - Writing value to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

My code is very simple, but can't seem to get rid of this error. I've tried assigning the strings to a variable and then assigning it, unprotecting the sheet, and putting the code in a new sub function. The error occurs in the second sub `Analyze()`.

```
Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINTIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Dim html As HTMLDocument

Sub Testing()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/latest_polls/elections/"

    Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Trying to reach RealClearPolitics.com"
        DoEvents

    Loop
    Set html = ie.document
    MsgBox html.DocumentElement.outerHTML
    Set ie = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = " "

    Call Analyze

End Sub

Sub Analyze()
    Dim polldate As String
    polldate = "date"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Cells.Clear

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(0, 0).Value = "Date"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(0, 1).Value = "Poll"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(0, 2).Value = "Page"

End Sub
```

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module code sheet and try to compile it. ([alt]+D,L)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cells()* must have indices starting with **1**, not **0**.

Answer (score 0):

Put `Call Analyze` before destructing the InternetExplorer object with `Set ie = Nothing`. Setting `html` to the ie object's document and then destructing ie leaves you with nothing as the document.